# XAML Datagrid, selected value but only for some columns

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Below is some code that almost works how I want. I am trying to get it so you click on a row and I take the programID and use it elsewhere, this part works. However I want nothing to happen if I click on the status column which has a built in combobox, how so i restrict it from using this column? I am using MVVM if that is needed

```
<DataGrid  x:Name="gridResult"  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"  SelectedValue ="{Binding ModelRequestSV}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" IsReadOnly="TRue" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  CanUserAddRows="false" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ModelRequestObs}" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Gray" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" Style="    {DynamicResource DataGridStyle1}" Margin="0,25,0,10"  >
        <DataGrid.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding
        MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick"
        Command="{Binding DoubleClickCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding ModelRequestSV}"/>
        </DataGrid.InputBindings>

<DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProgramID}" Header="Program ID" Width="100" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Cedant}" Header="Cedant" Width="300" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding UWCode}" Header="Underwriter" Width="145"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DateSubmitted}" Header="Date Submitted" Width="145"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding RequiredDate}" Header="Required Date" Width="145"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Priority}" Header="Priority" Width="145"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" Width="140">                    
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Width="110" Text="{Binding Status}" />
                            <ComboBox Text="{Binding Status}"
                            Width="20" Height="20"
                                      BorderThickness="0"

                            SelectedItem="{Binding Status}"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.StatusCodes, ElementName=userControl}"
                            SelectionChanged="DataGrid_SelectionChanged">

                            </ComboBox>
                        </StackPanel>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

here is my viewmodel logic

```
    private ModelRequest _modelRequestSV;
    private void NotifyProgrIdToParent()
    {
        CAT_Application_WPF.UI.App.MainViewModel.ProgIdCommand.Execute(_modelRequestSV.ProgramID.ToString());


    }
    public ModelRequest ModelRequestSV
    {
        get { return _modelRequestSV; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _modelRequestSV)
            {
                _modelRequestSV = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ModelRequestSV));
                if (ModelRequestSV != null)
                {
                    NotifyProgrIdToParent();
                }



            }
        }
    }
```

attempt. firstSelectedCell.Column.DisplayIndex.ToString() always returns "0" no matter where I click, what is the issue here?

```
    private void DataGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid myGrid = (System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid)sender; // now this is strongly typed so we can drill into its properties.
        var vm = (NotesManagerViewModel)DataContext;
        var selectedCells = myGrid.SelectedCells; // there can be more than one cell selected!  Which column is that in?
        if (selectedCells.Count > 0)
        {
            DataGridCellInfo firstSelectedCell = selectedCells[0]; // usually there will be only one selected.  If not, think about how you want to handle this.
            DataGridColumn ignoreThisColumn = myGrid.Columns[7]; // whichever column you want to ignore - you could also have several columns in an array...

            if (firstSelectedCell.Column.DisplayIndex.ToString() != ignoreThisColumn.DisplayIndex.ToString())
            {
               vm.NotifyProgrIdToParent();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your event handler DataGrid_SelectionChanged, you have an object sender - I forget offhand what the sender is (I think it's the DataGrid), but if you cast the sender to its type, then you can examine it in your code to see which column was clicked.  If you don't want to do anything when that column is clicked, then just skip the rest of your code.  This is not tested, but should point you in the right direction:

```
private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid myGrid = (DataGrid)sender; // now this is strongly typed so we can drill into its properties.

    var selectedCells = myGrid.SelectedCells; // there can be more than one cell selected!  Which column is that in?
    if (selectedCells.Count > 0)
    {
        DataGridCellInfo firstSelectedCell = selectedCells[0]; // usually there will be only one selected.  If not, think about how you want to handle this.
        DataGridColumn ignoreThisColumn = myGrid.Columns[1]; // whichever column you want to ignore - you could also have several columns in an array...

        if (firstSelectedCell.Column != ignoreThisColumn)
        {
            // do your logic here - we know they clicked on some other column...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i will edit for what my current logic is. Can i just take the logic from the VM and place it in there?

Comment: It looks like you have a double-click handled by code in your VM and a SelectionChanged handled by your code-behind (SelectionChanged="DataGrid_SelectionChanged") - this answer would apply to the code-behind.  If you want the checks to happen in your VM, then all you have to work with is the ModelRequestSV - I'm not sure if you can figure it out from that or not.  From your VM, you have no direct knowledge of the view (nor do you want this - it would violate MVVM).  Since "the column that was clicked" is view-dependent, this type of logic probably belongs in code behind.

Comment: Since your SelectedValue is already bound to ModelRequestSV, you don't really need to pass that as a command parameter on your double-click - you can already access ModelRequestSV in your VM.  Maybe you can repurpose that command parameter somehow to pass more info about which column was clicked.

Comment: NotifyProgrIdToParent(); I can just call from your code, however I am still not getting it to work on the if statement, playing with it now

Comment: Before the if, try outputting the column index that you clicked on and click on various columns to see what you get.  That will confirm that you are selecting the right column: Debug.WriteLine(myGrid.SelectedCells[0].Column.DisplayIndex.ToString());

Comment: Elemental Pete, view what I have done, I did the same thing and it always returns a "0" , not sure why